# PowerShell mail loses formatting

Tags: powershell, html-email

I'm in the process of creating a daily PowerShell-tip-mail for my team; Over the period we have created bunch of modules with hundreds of functions. The plan is to create a process to mail one function (get-help) every day. 
Following is the pseudo code:

```
$body       = Get-Help Get-Service -Detailed
$emailTO    = 'myemail@greatComp.com'
$emailFrom  = 'pstip@greatComp.com'
$smtpServer = 'smtp.server.com'
$subject    = "Daily PS Tip"
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpServer -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml
```

Although, we receive the mail, the formatting is lost. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Otherwise you'll need to build a properly formatted HTML body first.

Comment: Are you fine with just plain text indentation? perhaps just `$body = Get-Help Get-Service -Detailed | Out-String`. Using that with PetSerAl's suggestion might help too. Otherwise if you want HTML output you will actually have to format yourself like Ansgar suggets.

Comment: @Matt That worked! Thank you so much guys. Here's the solution:  use out-string along with <pre> tag!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  PetSerAl,  Ansgar Wiechers, and  Ansgar Wiechers. Here's the fix:

```
$body       = get-help get-service -Detailed |out-string 
$emailTO    = 'myemail@greatComp.com'
$emailFrom  = 'pstip@greatComp.com'
$smtpServer = 'smtp.server.com'
$subject    = "Daily PS Tip"
$body       = '<pre>' + $body + '</pre>'
send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpServer -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml
```